# How to configure wily with spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot

I have created an application as spring boot application,Now i want to integrate this application with wily,where i ll passed wily parameter in application to configure application.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it's a Spring Boot application shouldn't make any difference. If you're using an executable jar file, you'll need to configure the agent when you launch the jar, for example:

```
java -jar my-app.jar -javaagent:<Agent_Home>/Agent.jar -Dcom.wily.introscope.agentProfile=<Path_To_Agent_Profile>
```

If you're deploying your Spring Boot application as a war file to a servlet container or application server, you'll need to be make the equivalent configuration changes. The [documentation describes how to configure Tomcat](https://support.ca.com/cadocs/0/CA%20Application%20Performance%20Management%20as%20a%20Service%201%201%201-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/HTML/APMS--Install%20and%20Configure%20Agents/index.htm?toc.htm?install_agent_files.html).

Comment: its not working.I have passed with command line but not showing on wily